# how can i create html code (or other code) with input type text

Tags: javascript, html

How can I create HTML code (or other code) with input type text when users insert texts or numbers and click go the browser go to [domainurl.com/XXXinputtextXXX](http://domainurl.com/XXXinputtextXXX)

Thanks.

Comment: this is too generic.
can you please explain exactly what you need? what fwk you're using? code snippet?

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate some more? Show an example of what you've tried, provide some more context. What do you mean by create html code, and what is 'other code'.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit

Comment: mmm.. i dont know how to explain it.
its be simple i think.

i need to create simple page with place that user can wrote something, and "go"  button, when the user click 'GO' the page take him to mydomain + the text he wrote. like: http://example.com/usertext

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
function go(){
  var inp=document.getElementById('inp').value;
  window.location.href = "http://domainurl.com/XXX"+inp+"XXX";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp">
<input type="button" onclick="go();" value="go">
```

Comment: set location redirect, to a button

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onclick` event to trigger a function which redirects you using `window.location`:

* Note: The snippet will not take you to the website (so test it on your local device). Also the current website will redirect you if it doesn't understand the path, so you will only see your URL for a few seconds before it redirects.

```js
function openWindow() {
  let inputtext = document.getElementById('text-box').value; // Get the inputted text from text box
  window.location = "http://www.domainurl.com/XXX" +inputtext +"XXX"; // Take the user to the location with the input
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text-box" />
<button id="btn" onclick="openWindow()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: No, this is javascript, did you want it in php?

Comment: oh no no ... i try to understand how to do it, i know little html

Comment: Okay, I've updated the snippet to include comments. Let me know if you need further clarification